# Is there a hot key that automatically makes a group of vertices into a circle?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, workflow, transforms

I know that <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> makes vertices straightened on the z-axis, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make vertices into a complete circle on the z-axis with a hotkey?

Comment: try to click a vertice in edit mode with ```Alt``` pressed

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can also use the *To Sphere* function for that.
When used with a 2D mesh it makes a circle.

Mesh > Transform > To sphere
Shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and press <kbd>1</kbd> for a full circle.

[image]

Comment: +1 for showing basic built-int and read to use option instead of attacking the user with multitude of addons just for a simple task.

Comment: Thanks, I also like simple solutions :). Still, those suggested addons offer more functionality.

Comment: I have never seen this before: (Mesh > Transform > To Sphere). Thank you for sharing.  My thumb up.

Answer (score 10):

There's an add-on called "mesh tiny cad" which is still included in the standard installation of Blender (2.79 and 2.8+).

- Pick any three vertices in *Edit Mode*
- <kbd>RMB</kbd> -> TinyCad -> CCEN,

You'll see a circle of verts which you can adjust (radius, num of new verts)

This add-on/operator doesn't care about the orientation of your three vertices, it's not limited to X,Y or Z axis. It can be an arbitrary plane.

[image]

small documentation page for the add-on: https://zeffii.github.io/mesh_tiny_cad/

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you put into this addon. I'd like using it more frequently but I always ran into this issue that can't imagine what this *cool* abbreviations like "CCEN" or "VTX" are actually doing. Is there any documentation to get a better understanding of the operators?

Comment: sure: https://zeffii.github.io/mesh_tiny_cad/

Comment: On behalf of everyone: Thank you for making TinyCAD! :)

Comment: @JachymMichal and brockmann having tinycad out there is entirely selfish :)  it's the ultimate form of backup :)

Answer (score 7):

Please See [`Loop Tools`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/looptools.html). Click the image to enlarger.

[image]

You can install this addon via User Preferences. In the later version of Blender the addon appears with the context menu. (Click with the other mouse button). Now that you know the name of the addon you can see videos about how to use it on the famous video website or exactly here by searching BSE.

I have used some of the other techniques in past and present, presented in  the other answers.  They work well.  Loop Tools has many interesting features which go beyond the scope of your question for your future endeavors. There are always 33 ways to do something in Blender.

Some images may be from an earlier version of Blender.

[image]
A well populated cube with a hole and then loop tools was used.
[image]
The menu location of Loop Tools in an earlier version.
[image]
Loop Tools was enabled in User Preferences in this earlier version.