# How to remove triangular edges that appear after subdivision

Tags: modeling

I’m new at blender, and I decided to model a magic lamp as a start. I started by modeling the base of the lamp. I made it disk shaped. when I made the loop circular and used a subdivision modifier, those strange triangular edges appeared. How can I remove them? thank you, and sorry for bad english :slight_smile:
[image]

[image]

Edit: after removing n-gons, triangles disappeared! but edges became sharp.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). The triangles appear, because *Subdivision modifier* doesn't like the two n-gons (faces with more than 4 sides) in your model. Get rid of the n-gons, and it will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you, 
I subdivided edges and used triangulate faces, then  I used tris to quads, It worked fine and the triangles disappeared! but it made the shape of the lamp sharp (like a cuboid) instead of round (like a cylinder).
Thank you anyway, but do you have a way to return the round shape?
@JachymMichal

Comment: Hi :). It will require some manual tweaking, but [this thread could help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/166751/78972) with making your loopcuts into circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a lowpoly geometry and try to keep the mesh as regular as possible.

We don't know the final shape you want to obtain, but what I'd do is starting from a circle with few (8) vertices and extrude it along Z and scaling these extrusions.

Here is the geometry (in edit mode below with the starting circle selected), and above the same with a subdivision surface set to 1.

[image]

The main part is done simply extruding and scaling the base circle.

Then, when the shape looks ok for you, You can make the 'nose' part by selecting faces on the side and extrude them along X.

The hole (where the genius will come from) is done selecting top faces of the previous extrusion and insetting these faces using <kbd>I</kbd> and delete this inset.

[image]