# Is it possible to make this in one piece?

Tags: modeling

I stuck over here. How do I make the middle part to a Cylinder and keep this as one piece? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Hello :). You can turn the rectangle into a cylinder using the [*To Sphere* operation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166773/78972). Just subdivide the top/bottom edge loop.

Comment: The rest of the geometry turns into a mess. lol