# Is there a tool/option/add-on to generate a polygon circle that intersects the currently selected vertices?

Tags: mesh

I'm looking for an option or tool or add-on or something that would allow me to create a new polygon circle that goes through the currently selected vertices.

So, imagine you're on edit mode working on a mesh, you select 2 or more vertices and boom!, you get a new circle made of vertices and edges, with the starting vertex of that circle intersecting the first vertex of your selection, the last vertex of the circle intersecting the last vertex of your selection, and if you selected more than 2 vertices the circle will try to intersect them as well.

Is there anything similar to this? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hello :). I'm not sure I understand, perhaps some images would help. But maybe [TinyCAD addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166781/) is what you want?

Comment: Specifically, its CCEN function