# How would I go about creating an oval/circular cut within 4 vertices?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a model of the Xbox One X for learning purposes. I'm currently trying to create this oval shape part shown in the image below.
[image]

My attempt to this was using the knife tool and and moving vertices manually to create the curvature around the corners (progress shown in the image below) but found it painstakingly slow and not very accurate and I know there's definitely an easier way to do this.
[image]

How can I create the circle/oval shape more efficiently. I want to create the oval shape within the 4 vertices as shown in image below? I think another easier way I would do this is to add another cube mesh, minimize and add subdivisions so it takes the rectangular/oval shape and move it to that area and cut a piece from the main model from it but is there a way where I can just tell Blender to automatically create a circle/oval lines within the 4 vertices?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your topology looks like this so let's start from here:
[image]

Firstly remove those extra n-gons and make it cleaner

Make a cross from loop cuts like this:
[image]

Now you have two options...

Option 1 vertice bevel, select 1 vert in the middle of the cross and use Ctrl+Shift+B and pull with mouse: (shape it and clean it with knife)
[image]
[image]

Option 2 (without knife cleaning) with Insert:

Select 4 faces and insert new faces with I
[image]
[image]
Use Looptools (it's a default addon that you can activate in preferences)
[image]
[image]

Both options will give you nice symmetrical hole that you can shape to your needs much easier, goo luck

Comment: Oh, beveling a vertex is a really neat idea! And to make a circle, [you don't even need an addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/166751/78972) :)

Comment: Well you don't but I think that Looptools is the fastest possible idea if you want a perfect circle and not a bit oval-like in your idea, and even if it is I would still prefer just to shape it with Scale :D